# Typing "ctor" to create constructor

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2017

I've seen a video [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-listview-customization-using-textcell-imagecell-and-viewcell/) where a coder types "ctor" at 4:42, and the IDE automatically creates a constructor for him.

I tried to do the same, but for me, the IDE doesn't do that. IntelliSense does offer "ctor", but when I select it, nothing happens.

What is the trick that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please check your Code Snippets Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + K, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) if there are Visual C# file in Csharp language?

[Code Snippets Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAhoC.png)

Go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Text Editor* → *C#* → *IntelliSense*, under the Snippets behaviour section: Make sure "Always include snippets" is selected.